# Setting Time input format in Frontend

Tags: javascript, frontend

I'm trying to modify the below code in React Typescript. I want to return the input value in time format like - "Thu Jan 01 2022 13:03:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" any suggestions how to do it?

Full Code: https://codepen.io/dcode-software/pen/jOwVqGO

```js
function getTimeStringFromPicker(timePicker) {
    const selects = getSelectsFromPicker(timePicker);

    return `${selects.hour.value}:${selects.minute.value} ${selects.meridiem.value}`;
}

function numberToOption(number) {
    const padded = number.toString().padStart(2, "0");

    return `<option value="${padded}">${padded}</option>`;
}

activate();
```

Comment: don't post links to code, post the code itself inside the question :) you can use snippets to post html/css/js code

Comment: sorry first time using this website :]

Comment: don't worry about it

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `Date` object and set the hours and minutes on it. From there you get convert it to a string. Like this:

```
function getTimeStringFromPicker(timePicker) {
    const selects = getSelectsFromPicker(timePicker);
    const d = new Date();
    d.setMinutes(selects.minute.value);
    
    // setHours takes in hours in 24hr format
    if (selects.meridiem.value === "pm") {
        d.setHours(selects.hour.value + 12);
    } else {
        d.setHours(selects.hour.value);
    }

    return d.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can reach a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object somehow, its [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) method can do something like that (the actual parameters are described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#options).

```js
let date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "EST",
  dateStyle: 'full',
  timeStyle: 'full',
  hour12: false // this is because you seem to want a 24-hour format
}));
```

If you need more, [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) might be a library to check.

Comment: moment.js is kind of outdated. You might want to consider newer alternatives.

Comment: @MichaelM. I don't know moment.js either. So the most I can do is removing it.